# Missing filesystems in new Ubuntu 18.04 installation , embedded target

Tags: partition, fhs

I installed a new Ubuntu 18.04 on my disk and noticed the following filesystems:

1. /dev/nvme0n1p1 mounted on: /
2. none           mounted on: /dev
3. tmpfs          mounted on: /dev/shm
4. tmpfs          mounted on: /run
5. tmpfs          mounted on: /run/lock
6. tmpfs          mounted on: /sys/fs/cgroup
7. tmpfs          mounted on: /run/user/120
8. tmpfs          mounted on: /run/user/1000

a. Its missing quite important filesystems such as /tmp , /var.
Is it ok? is it normal? should I add them manually?

b. I read that /var , /tmp should reside in their own partitions.
What is the recommended partition size for allocating to these filesystems on separate partitions?

c. what is none? (mounted on /dev)

d. /proc is missing as well. I need to configure it?

Thanks

Comment: Questions a and d self-answer, don't they? Your system is running, so you don't have to change it. Also, general question: why would you in 2023 install Ubuntu 18.04? That is currently running out of its support phase.

Comment: re question b.: Since you don't need separate partitions as per self-answering a., you don't need to consider sizes (what you've read is probably from an obsolete or low-quality source. The Ubuntu installer installs a pretty usual, well -working system. People use Ubuntu exactly because a default setup has nothing to fundamentally fix)

Comment: I apologize, I didn't understand your answer. I don't blame the Ubuntu system for missing filesystems but try to understand why its ok not to work with them. I read that each system have to have the /proc , /var , /tmp for different daemons to work properly for example. So how it doesn't cause problems in the Ubuntu system?

Comment: because the tool you used to list the mounted filesystem just hides /proc (amongst at least one other essential pseudo-filesystem), and what you read about /var and /tmp is wrong.